# Invalid query generated for Oracle database

Tags: .net, entity-framework, oracle11g, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I am using Entity Framework 5 and code first for the database modeling and mapping.  When I attempt to execute the query via an API call I receive an error that states `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`.  Reviewing the query it appears to be in a format that is not typical for Oracle queries.

My .config connection string is

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Entities" connectionString="Data Source=development;
                                         User ID=user;Password=password"
                       providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Within the OnModelCreating() I am mapping as follows

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Job>().ToTable("Table1", "schema");
```

The query that is being generated that I can see in the debugger does not execute via a copy/paste to Oracle.

```
SELECT "Extent1"."ColumnName" AS "ColumnName"
FROM "schema"."Table1" "Extent1"
```

I would have thought that the fact I am using the `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` provider that the query would be generated appropriately.  How do I convince EF5 that it should generate the query in a specific fashion to be compatible with Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query itself is valid, it's just that because the identifier names are wrapped in double quotes, then the names become case sensitive.

As you probably didn't define a specific casing for your table and schema name, you should probably just upper case it (default Oracle casing) when creating the mapping in EF:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Job>().ToTable("TABLE1", "SCHEMA"); // upper case.
```

Comment: I never considered or realized that case sensitivity would cause issues in Oracle?

Comment: We usually don't need to care. But EF is forcing you to care by generating the names in double quotes.  Not sure if there is a way to tell EF not to do that.

Comment: I found via SE a mapper extension called Dapper.FluentMap that appears to provide some of this functionality.  https://github.com/henkmollema/Dapper-FluentMap